# cron job fails to restart services

Tags: cron, solaris, restart

I have a simple script that stops and starts the services (of Oracle Hyperion)

```
#!bin/ksh

/path/to/dir/stop.sh

sleep 1200

/path/to/dir/start.sh
```

I have scheduled it for every night and it does run, however there is an issue with database connectivity afterwards. But when i run `stop.sh` and `start.sh` manually, there is no such issue. Obviously the job had not run completely.

Here's the output from `crontab -l`

```
00 02 * * * /export/home/oracle/scheduled_restart.sh
```

Could someone please advise on the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the cronjob line just to check?

Comment: @fedorqui I have added the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual cause for cron jobs to differ from command line during execution of the exact same code is environment, specifically the variables like ORACLE_SID, TWO_TASK, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and so on.

Assuming the oracle user own the crontab:
When a job is run by crond it does the equivalent of su oracle, not su - oracle.  Try doing something to ensure that the command sources everything the oracle user would normally source during login.

To see what is going on:

```
/export/home/oracle/scheduled_restart.sh && set > /tmp/my_variables.txt
```

You do not need the `/bin/sh`  if the `/export/home/oracle/scheduled_restart.sh` file is executable.
It should have a shebang on line 1.  ex: `#!/bin/ksh`  for korn shell or whatever shell you use.

Comment: I'm not sure if the oracle user 'owns' crontab, but the user is in the cron.allow list, along with root. I'll try it when i get the chance and let you know how it goes

Comment: "owns" means the user can create and edit a crontab.  cron.allow does that.  Since you executed crontab -l okay, then you are good to go.

Comment: We added the lines to set the environment variables in the script, and then it was alright.